# Form minimize and ShowInTaskbar=False --> Controls location to -768?

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms

I have the simplified source code:

```
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      Dim Panel1 As New Panel
      Panel1.Size = New Size(4000, 4000)
      Panel1.Location = New Point(-2000, -2000)
      Me.Controls.Add(Panel1)
      Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
      Debug.WriteLine(Panel1.Location.ToString) '--> {X=-2000,Y=-2000}
      ShowInTaskbar = False
      Debug.WriteLine(Panel1.Location.ToString) '--> {X=-768,Y=-768}  WHY?
  End Sub
```

My problem is, when form send to minimize with "ShowInTaskbar = False" then if control X or Y location over then -768, the form relocationing this to -768.
For example:
Panel1 position is {X=-2000,Y=-2000}
But after minimized form, the form set this automatically to {X=-768,Y=-768}

How to disable this automation relocationing.

Development Environment VB2013 .NET2.0 Win7 64bit.

Comment: You are putting too much code in the Load event handler.  This belongs in the constructor, Sub New.  The ShowInTaskbar property is a dangerous property when the window has already been created, like it is in the Load event.  The window needs to be re-created to make the property effective and that often has side-effects.  Another workaround is to move it to the first line in your Load event handler.

Comment: The original code length is over then 4000 row. In the original source code, the minimze and taskbar opreation run in Button click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to trace back to what is causing this problem.
When you change the **ShowInTaskbar** property, this call the **MyBase.RecreateHandle()**, which calls the **RecreateHandleCore()**.
Here call 2 method: **Me.DestroyHandle()** and **Me.CreateHandle()**.
These methods call childcontrols same methods.
I couldn't track more. I think this is a Windows bug.

The following code gives the same result if the form is minimized:

```
    Dim Panel1 As New Panel
    Panel1.Size = New Size(4000, 4000)
    Panel1.Location = New Point(-2000, -2000)
    Me.Controls.Add(Panel1)
    
    Debug.WriteLine("Panel handle: " & Panel1.Handle.ToString & " Panel Bounds: " & Panel1.Bounds.ToString)
    Debug.WriteLine("Form handle: " & Me.Handle.ToString & " Form Bounds: " & Me.Bounds.ToString)
    
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
    
    Debug.WriteLine("----- Minimized -----")
    Debug.WriteLine("Panel handle: " & Panel1.Handle.ToString & " Panel Bounds: " & Panel1.Bounds.ToString)
    Debug.WriteLine("Form handle: " & Me.Handle.ToString & " Form Bounds: " & Me.Bounds.ToString)
    
    Panel1.[GetType]().GetMethod("DestroyHandle", BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(Panel1, Nothing)
    Panel1.[GetType]().GetMethod("CreateHandle", BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(Panel1, Nothing)
    
    Debug.WriteLine("----- Destroyed Handle -----")
    Debug.WriteLine("Panel handle: " & Panel1.Handle.ToString & " Panel Bounds: " & Panel1.Bounds.ToString)
    Debug.WriteLine("Form handle: " & Me.Handle.ToString & " Form Bounds: " & Me.Bounds.ToString)
```

My solution, add this line after Panel is created. Not so pretty, but working.

```
    AddHandler Panel1.HandleCreated, Sub()
                                         Panel1.Location = New Point(-2000, -2000)
                                     End Sub
```

Full solution code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim Panel1 As New Panel
    AddHandler Panel1.HandleCreated, Sub()
                                         Panel1.Location = New Point(-2000, -2000)
                                     End Sub
    Panel1.Size = New Size(4000, 4000)
    Panel1.Location = New Point(-2000, -2000)
    Me.Controls.Add(Panel1)
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
    Debug.WriteLine(Panel1.Location.ToString) '--> {X=-2000,Y=-2000}
    ShowInTaskbar = False
    Debug.WriteLine(Panel1.Location.ToString) '--> {X=-2000,Y=-2000}  Work
End Sub
```